# Email Worksheet when multiple sheets are Open

Tags: excel, vba

Just wanted to know i have opened a workbook and under that there are multiple sheets with different names , now i need to email sheet with name Combined , however i am getting an error on the below code , please help i am getting compile error

```
Sub Mail_ActiveSheet()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
    Dim Destwb As Workbook
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook

'Copy the ActiveSheet to a new workbook
ActiveSheet.Copy=>Sheets ("Combined").copy

Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
With Destwb
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        'You use Excel 97-2003
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        'You use Excel 2007-2016
        Select Case Sourcewb.FileFormat
        Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
        Case 52:
            If .HasVBProject Then
                FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
            Else
                FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            End If
        Case 56: FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
        Case Else: FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
        End Select
    End If
End With

'    'Change all cells in the worksheet to values if you want
'    With Destwb.Sheets(1).UsedRange
'        .Cells.Copy
'        .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'        .Cells(1).Select
'    End With
'    Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Save the new workbook/Mail it/Delete it
TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
TempFileName = "Part of " & Sourcewb.Name & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With Destwb
    .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = "sachin.gupta2209@gmail.com"
        .CC = "sachin.gupta2209@gmail.com;"
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Samples"
        .Body = "Hi Please find attached"
        .Attachments.Add Destwb.FullName
        'You can add other files also like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    .Close savechanges:=False
End With

'Delete the file you have send
Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This exact works, appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Although you haven't said where the error is being thrown, I would say that you need to change the code on line 20 from:

```
ActiveSheet.Copy=>Sheets ("Combined").copy
```

to:

```
sourcewb.Sheets("Combined").Copy
```

in order to create the new active workbook set as `Destwb` to be emailed afterwards.